# New to Object Oriented Design

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis

I am new to object oriented design. I am looking forward to some tips on how to model the below mentioned requirement using objects.

**Requirement:** A program has many Students. A program logs in to the application. First page displays a table of all the Students belonging to the program (Table Columns - Id, First name, last name, age, sex, etc. ). The Id is a link. By clicking the Id, the individual student page is displayed. In this page, an individual student related activities can be done - for eg. edit address, change name, add comments etc.

**My Solution:** Two Classes

Program - Will model a single program, perform all activities related to it and encapsulate all program related db tables.

Student - Will model a single student and perform all activities related to it and encapsulate all student specific db tables.

So far, so good.

In order to fetch details of all students related to a program, from Program object I need to call a method called '**fetch_student_details**'.

The Question is where should this method be written? Should it be a Student Class method or Program Class method.

If I write this method in program class, how will the Program class handle it?

(a) First identify the list of student_ids that belong to it and for each id, instantiate a Student Class and get the specific student related information from it. DB: Each instantiated student object will run a query to fetch its information. So 100 students, 100 queries.

OR

(b) Fetch  the list of student ids related to the program and fetch the student information directly for all the students. Db: Single query to fetch all the needed information.

Comment: If you can do this in a single query, then by all means do. APIs should be designed to make an efficient implementation possible.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you can, go for solution (b). Students and Programs, in fact, are two differet entities that can exist independently, and you don't break encapsulation.

With solution (a) you need to pollute Program's interface by adding a method for each possible information that you want to get from the Students.

As final suggestion, if you want to learn OO Design, start by reading the book "Design patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides (AKA "The gang of four").